# QT: add SvgWidget to layout

Tags: qt, layout, svg

I need to create circle tiles for a board game, so I made svgWigets and tried to add them to a layout for display them.

```
QLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
QSvgWidget tile(":/gameIcons/white.svg");
layout->addWidget(tile);
```

But i get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'QLayout::addWidget(QSvgWidget&)'
layout->addWidget(tile);
```

I guess svgWidgets are widgets, so i don't understand why this error happens, so i'm asking for the correct form to do it, i'm a novice anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use pointer to object, not whole object. So it should be:

```
QLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
QSvgWidget *tile = new QSvgWidget(":/gameIcons/white.svg");
layout->addWidget(tile);
```

It can be also:

```
QLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
QSvgWidget tile(":/gameIcons/white.svg");
layout->addWidget(&tile);
```

But in this case `tile` creates in stack so it can be delete in your code (from your small code snippet I can't figure out where are you using this code so the best way is to use pointer) and `tile` will not be valid.